# harvard-style tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

There are currently 4 questions with the tag [harvard-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvard-referencing). Our other major bibliography style tags (apa-style, chicago-style, mla-style) all have the form `<name>-style`.  It would seem to make sense to change [harvard-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvard-referencing) to [harvard-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvard-style).

Comment: Sounds fine to me

Comment: @Joseph Not being a retagging expert, do I just add the `harvard-style` tag to the existing questions and then a mod will delete the old tag?

Comment: That does tend to be the way, but I think we can do this from the mod panel directly.

Comment: @Joseph That would be great.  I'm not opposed to helping, but if you can do it with a click or two that would make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I now merged [harvard-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvard-referencing) to [harvard-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvard-style) but without creating a, IMHO unnecessary, synonym. I don't think the first form will come back. The auto-completion will show the new form when someone enters `harvard`.

Such tag renaming can be done by the moderator using one of the moderation tools and does not create new revisions for the tagged questions, which is the preferable way.